# Multiple mutable queries with Legion ECS

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, entity-component-system

I am using the Legion ECS and trying to use multiple mutable queries and running into some borrow checker constraints.

I basically want to update the state of components by comparing with all of the other components.

In essence - make components blue if they are adjacent to another component.

```
let components = <&Component>::query()
  .iter(world)
  .collect();

<&Component>::query()
  .iter_mut(world)
  .for_each(|component| {
     // for each c in components 
     // make component blue if c is adjacent to this component
   })
```

Error with above is `cannot borrow` *ecs `as mutable more than once at a time`

```
    |
128 |             .iter(&ecs)
    |                   ---- immutable borrow occurs here
...
134 |             .iter_mut(&mut ecs)
    |                       ^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
135 |             .for_each(|(_, fov)| {
136 |                 let fovs: HashSet<Point> = components
    |                                            --- immutable borrow later captured here by closure
```

Is there another way to do the above?
I've thought that cloning the initial collection would decouple me from the World/ecs. But even with a clone, iterating through the component collection is an immutable borrow.

Comment: Note that `<(&Component)>` is equal to `<&Component>`.

Comment: Thanks ... typo as my actual code is more complex and queries for a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `components` vector is a vector containing *references* to `Component`, which borrows from `world` and means you can't mutably borrow it later when you go to edit the component.

You can resolve this a couple of ways:

- Clone the components when creating the `compontents` vector. Easy, but requires more allocation.
- Iterate over the components immutably at first and keep a buffer of changes, then apply those changes. [`CommandBuffer`](https://docs.rs/legion/latest/legion/systems/struct.CommandBuffer.html) can help with this - you can even add it to a system and legion will take care of creating and flushing.
- Iterate over `Entities`, possibly with a component filter (IDK if that locks the storage its filtering on), and use `world.entry[_mut]` to access components one at a time. Won't require allocation, but might have worse performance.

Comment: Thanks! I sort-of got most of the way to the core realisation last night and it seems so obvious now. Cloning the collection gives you a new collection of references. Duh! 
Really demonstrates the power of the Rust model, protecting you from yourself.